# Deciding pixel position in n X n Grid

Tags: c#, algorithm, silverlight, graphics

Let me introduce my project:
    My project is about drawing object in n X n grid. in silver light.

What i have done?
   http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/174093/16x16-DotMatrix from this i have drawn grid in sliver-light. 
    I have to drawn circle or any curve or any letter in any font-type on that grid. that i have done. 
    Now, what i need is to change the color of rectangle  from which the curve passes.I have use raster scan and also dda curve drawing algo...........

please suggest me best algo.